# Ajax call doesn't return data after echoed

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

The ajax call successfully update the record but doesn't return the string of echo. This script was working before but might be because of some upgrade it stops working. It is working fine on my local system but when I move it to bluehost server then it does not work.

Here is my Ajax call:

```
// call to ajax script to update site
        function autopost_update_site() {

            // get base directory url
            var baseDir = jQuery('#baseDir').val();
            var id = jQuery('#site_id').val();
            var site_name = jQuery('#site_name').val();
            var site_url = jQuery('#site_url').val();
            var is_active;
            if ( jQuery('#active_radio').is(':checked') ){
                is_active = '1';
            } else {
                is_active = '0';
            }

            var username = jQuery('#login_username').val();
            var login_pass = jQuery('#login_pass').val();

            // call to ajax script to update script
            jQuery.ajax( {
                type: "POST",
                url: baseDir + "/autopost_ajax_actions.php",
                data: "id=" + id + "&site_name=" + site_name + "&site_url=" + site_url + "&is_active="+ is_active + "&username=" + username + "&login_pass="+login_pass +"&action=update_site",


                beforeSend: function() {
                    jQuery('#update_site_button').attr("disabled", true);
                    // shortcode edit button
                    jQuery('#update_site_button').html('Updating...');
                    // admin page edit button
                    jQuery('#update_site_button').val('Updating...');
                },
                complete: function() {
                    jQuery('#update_site_button').attr("disabled", false);
                    // shortcode edit button
                    jQuery('#update_site_button').html('Update');
                    // admin page edit button
                    jQuery('#update_site_button').val('Update');
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("Result: " + data); // NOTHING IS HAPPENING HERE, NO ALERT DATA
                    if (jQuery.trim(data) === "success") {
                        alert("Site updated.");
                        // refresh page
                        window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 200);
                    } else {
                        alert("Some error occured, Please try again.");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Here is my custom php script for ajax actions:

```
// update site
    if ( $_POST['action'] == 'update_site' && isset ($_POST['id']) ) {

            // collect site data
            $site_name = $wpdb->escape($_POST['site_name']);
            $site_id = intval($wpdb->escape($_POST['id']));
            $site_url = $wpdb->escape($_POST['site_url']);
            $username = $wpdb->escape($_POST['username']);
            $login_pass = $wpdb->escape($_POST['login_pass']);
            $is_active = $wpdb->escape($_POST['is_active']);

            $query = $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE " . $autopost_sites_table_name . " SET site_name = %s, site_url = %s, username = %s, login_pass = %s, is_active = %s WHERE id = %s", $site_name, $site_url, $username, $login_pass, $is_active, $site_id);               
            #$log->LogDebug($query);
            // execute query
            $result = $wpdb->query($query);

            #$log->LogDebug($result);

            if ( $result !== FALSE ||  $result !== 0) {

                // return success
                $response = "success";
                #$log->LogDebug($response);
                echo $response; // THIS RESPONSE IS NOT SHOWING ON AJAX SUCCESS 

            } else {
                $log->LogError("Failed to update site with ID: " . $_POST['id']);
                echo "Failed to update site.";
            }

    }
```

Can anyone tell me what is missing?

Comment: "NOTHING IS HAPPENING HERE, NO ALERT DATA" — If you aren't getting an alert, then the success function isn't running. Look at your browser's  developer tools' net tab. Look at the HTTP request and its response. Is it what you expect? What errors are reported?

Comment: is your error log being invoked?

Comment: Using chrome inspect, check the network section to analyse whether the ajax is being sent correctly and what the response back is.

Comment: Did you try adding an `error` handler in your ajax call? You're simply assuming everything should succeed.

Comment: I'm getting this error in chrome network: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://unwaveringmedia.net/wp-content/plugins/elite-auto-post/autopost_ajax_actions.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.unwaveringmedia.net' is therefore not allowed access. admin.php?page=autopost_manage_sites.php&parent_tab=manage_site&child_tab=view_sites:1

Comment: Have you tried adding die(); after the echo as in the answer below.  It is needed for AJAX in Wordpress plugins to return a response otherwise other Worpress scripts will run and cause unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I just added header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
to my ajax action script and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Change **`data`** as follows

```
data:{
      id:id,
      site_name:site_name,
      site_url:site_url ,
      is_active:is_active ,
      username:username,
      login_pass:login_pass,
      action:"update_site"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As It is mentioned that the script is working great on local but not working on server. So it was some server issue and I was getting error for "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in chrome network.

I just added

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

to my ajax action script and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score -2):

after

```
echo $response;
```

put

```
die();
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

In the example it says:

```
function my_action_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

    $whatever += 10;

    echo $whatever;

    die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}
```

Comment: That's not going to work. The script will stop it's own execution once it reaches the end of itself, which it does in this case.

Comment: Did you try?  I've had to do it this way before. Maybe it's just a Wordpress thing, but getting a response to echo from a Wordpress ajax call needs to call die() or you don't get the output.

Comment: See http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Where it says:
die(); // this is required to return a proper result

Comment: But according to http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins it's needed for Wordpress AJAX call to work.

Comment: ANd if that's what wordpress relies on for that sort of thing, I doubt I'll be using WP anytime soon. Not to mention, that's for AJAX plugins, there is probably a lot more going on behind the scenes that you don't explicitly know about.